# T4MVCJs with MVC 5 and .NET 4.5.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, t4mvc

Is there a way to configure T4MVCJs to work with `MVC 5 (.Net 4.5.1)` ?  I installed the latest version (`on Nuget`) which claims to use `T4MVC Version 2.6.57`.  In the end, I just want to use this or something like it via a T4 Template that will generate the paths for ActionResults, etc. that I can use for my JavaScript files in MVC 5.

Edit: The version of T4MvcJs is T4MvcJs.1.0.13.

Answer (score 0):

T4MvcJs apparently didn't install all needed requirements.  I had to install T4MVCExtensions (also in the Nuget Package Manager).  After doing this, T4MvcJs started to generate the JavaScript file.